# Defer loading images in a numerical range?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS that loads images based on their numerical value in a range of numbers (e.g., 3.png). I’d like to defer loading of images after frame 59 until after the first 59 frames have been loaded. How can I accomplish this?

```
    for (i = 1; i < totalFrames + 1; i++) {
        var ext = '.png';
        image = new Image();

        if (isDesktop) {
            if (i % incr === 0) {
                num = i;
            }
            // Need to load these frames on desktop:
            if (
                i === 1 ||
                i === 59 ||
                i === 151 ||
                i === 256 ||
                i === 317 ||
                i === 358 ||
                i === 400
            ) {
                num = i;
            }
        } else {
            // Need to load only these frames on mobile
            if (
                (i >= 39 && i <= 59) ||
                (i >= 131 && i <= 151) ||
                (i >= 236 && i <= 256) ||
                (i >= 298 && i <= 491)
            ) {
                num = i;
            }
        }

        image.src = '/assets/images/innovation-sequence/final-stills/' + (num) + ext;
        image.setAttribute('data-num', i);
        images.push(image);
        image.onload = function() {
            loadedCount++;
            if (loadedCount < lastPng) {
                Loader.setProgress(loadedCount / lastPng);
            }
            if (parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-num'), 10) >= lastPng && !relinquished) {
                relinquished = true;
                setupLayout();
                Loader.restart();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have an image.onload() event, and you're counting images loaded with loadedCount; what's missing? What do you mean exactly by "defer loading"?

Comment: Currently, a loading overlay blocks the page from being visible until all the images are loaded. I'd like the loading overlay to disappear after (let's say) the first 59 images are loaded. Once the overlay disappears, then continue loading the rest.

Comment: Ok, so you want to prevent users from doing anything until there's at least 59 (ish) images already loaded, right?

Comment: Yes, basically. Release the overlay after 59 images being loaded.

Comment: It would be better to remove the onLoad() event binding from the FOR loop and attach the event to a parent element using delegation. Please post your HTML so we can take a look at that.